# *Inject" interface method implementation during compilation

Tags: java, enums, proxy

Consider the following:

```
public interface MyFilter {

  @FilterAttribute
  String getAttribute();
}

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@Implementor(AutoEnumFilterAttribute.class)
public @interface FilterAttribute{
}

public enum MyEnumType2Filter implements MyFilter{
  TYPE0,
  TYPE1;
}

public enum MyEnumType2Filter implements MyFilter{
  TYPE20,
  TYPE21;
}
```

and much more ...

the MyFilter.getAttribute() implementation will look something like this in all cases.

```
...
public String getAttribute() {
  return "attribute."+name().toLowerCase()+".filter";
}
...
```

Which as we can see is unnecessary repetition implementation in every enum that implements this interface.
Of course i can have a separate helper class which i do something like this

```
public final class MyFilterHelp {

  public static String getAttribute(MyFilter filter) {
    //check that it is an enum then,
    return "attribute."+filter.name().toLowerCase()+".filter";
  }
}

or
public enum MyEnum implements MyFilter {
   TYPE20;

   private String attribute;
   private MyEnum () {
      this.attribute = "attribute."+name().toLowerCase()+".filter";
   }

   public  Strign getAttribute() {
     return this.attribute;
   }
}
```

But this first options separates the attributes from the enum, and the section option still requires implementation for every enum that implements this interface.

My vision is to have.

```
public class AutoEnumFilterAttribute<MyFilter> {

      public String getAttribute(MyFilter filter) {
        //check that it is an enum then,
        return "attribute."+filter.name().toLowerCase()+".filter";
      }
}
```

And use my enum filters normally as (the AutoEnumFilterAttribute acting somewhat like a proxy):

```
MyFilter filter = ...
String attribute = filter.getAttribute();
```

I surmise i can do this by kind of "injecting" the implementation of the MyFilter.getAttribute() in every enum that implements this interface during compile time.

Any idea on how to go about this?
Considering jdk7 or below.

As answered, one can do this using java8 [default method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with **Java 8**, you can go for a [default method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in your interface. If you combine that with specifying the enum method `name()`, then you're pretty close to what you seem to want.

```
interface MyFilter {

    default String getAttribute() {
        return "attribute."+name().toLowerCase()+".filter";
    } // you no longer have to implement this in your enums

    String name(); // you need to specify this method here in order to use it in the default method
}
```

Since every enum already implements name(), there is no penalty for your existing classes (i.e. no refactoring) and you get the API method you need in a concise way.

If you're working with an **older version of Java**, then your solution will be rather complicated. You may consider writing an [Annotation Preprocessor](https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/). I myself haven't used them, but I've seen a demo at one time and have read a bit about it. Please remember that I might not get everything right.

A very short summary is that you can mark classes with a custom-made annotation, and let an Annotation Preprocessor pick these classes up and auto-generate some code for them. The best part is that your compiler will know this at compile time, because you can configure the preprocessor to run before the compiler. As a result, the compiler will not balk at any methods you added at 'pre-compile' time.

So my idea would be to create something like this:

```
interface MyFilter {

    String getAttribute();
}

@AddGetAttribute
enum MyEnumType2Filter implements MyFilter {
    TYPE20, TYPE21
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.CLASS)
@interface AddGetAttribute {}

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.blagae.AddGetAttribute")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class AttributeProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public AttributeProcessor() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                                   RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        /* this method should let you add the source code for your enums
           see links below for some basic examples
           you will need to try and add a method to your existing class,
           instead of creating a new class file as these links do.
         */
        return false;
    }
}
```

The links I promised:

[using Velocity](https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/annotation-generators/)

Comment: Then I guess you should either mention that in your question, or switch to 8 :-)

Comment: I added a big chunk to my answer about Annotation Preprocessors. I hope it helps - and that the technique is possible for enums